# php passing a variable via onLoad

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php page which is using javascript to produce a calendar on the page. I am trying to pass a variable so that I can reference it on the loaded page.

Below is the script I am using to generate the calendar(along with several others)

```
<script language="javaScript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    showmonth = month;
    showyear = year;
    var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

and below is the way I am displaying this onto the php page:

```
<body onLoad="initialCalendar();">
```

I have tried using `'<?php echo $page; ?>'` and `'<?php $_POST['$page'] ?>'` in the brackets of initial calendar()

however I am having no luck, I hope I have explained correctly and in enough detail to make sence, however if you need anything more please just comment

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: What is `$page`? Do you know there must be accepted argument to a funcion to be passed? Passing `fn(anything)` will not work if the function is defined as `function fn(/*nothing here*/) {/*...*/}`.

Comment: your javascript function have no argument so how you want to pass an argument to it ?

Comment: $page a variable passed from the previous page in the URL, like so: http://localhost/project/calendar.php?page=something

I am trying to grab the $page variable allowing me to have different calendars for different events.

Comment: after adding argument to your function while declarin then past argument like this $_GET['page'] not $_POST['page']

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the layout of your `$_POST` array, but if I understood the question right you should try:

```
<body onLoad="initialCalendar('<?php echo $_POST['page'];?>');">
```

and change your function declaration to:

```
function initialCalendar(page){
```

Note that I've used single quotes `'` around the value which PHP outputs. This to ensure that it didn't break anything if the value is a string.

Comment: Hi, this is not working but I think with more information I can explain better.

$page a variable passed from the previous page in the URL, like so: http://localhost/project/calendar.php?page=something

I am trying to grab the $page variable allowing me to have different calendars for different events.

Comment: If it is passed by url you'll have to use `$_GET['page'];` instead

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing variable through parameters like

```
localhost/project/calendar.php?page=something
```

use `$_GET['page']` rather than the `$_POST`